# Modern polytheism, who are the new gods?

Tags: religion, urban-fantasy

Background:

By spreading themselves too thin, and then through a series of events the current mono theistic gods accidentally kill themselves.  (This is very sad, and I don't wish to offend anyone who was fond of them.)

So now like after a forest fire, many small gods are sprouting up.

These new gods are very similar to the Greek and Roman gods. 
They epitomise facets of human nature (love, war, etc), technology (farming, harvest, writing, music , pottery etc), and nature (the sea, the forests etc).

So! **What would be some interesting gods to have in our modern world?**

For example a modern god may be a god of fashion. He/She may help with inspiration or help a faithful new designer with a chance meeting with a fashion magazine editor etc. They could also be fickle and decide they don't like a designer anymore or go out of their way to impede a label if the owner became too prideful or something.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It looks like you're just pooling for ideas, and [every answer is equally valid, which makes this question something you should not ask here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Finagle and Murphy the twin gods of breakage and failure. The Beta testers of the universe.

Comment: Reminds me a lot of *American Gods* by Neil Gaiman...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would a scientifically advanced future community believe in multiple gods?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/67556/why-would-a-scientifically-advanced-future-community-believe-in-multiple-gods)

Comment: There are polytheistic religions such as shinto and hinduism who have, and continue to, added deities according to modern life.

Answer (score 6):

There are many new developments that weren't known to the original polytheistic religions, and so are crying out for some deistic oversight. New positions which need to be filled include:

- God of Genetic Modification
- God of Nuclear War (distinct from the god of Conventional War)
- God of Space Travel
- God of the Internet (perhaps he's the one who converts Facebook likes into food for the poor)
- God of Transport (covering everything from cars to planes)
- God of Hedge Funds
- God of Television
- God of Coffee
- God of Football (who is worshipped differently in the United States than anywhere else)

Comment: The God of Football already exists, and is named Bill Belichik.

Answer (score 4):

I think it was in the [*Thursday Next* books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thursday_Next) that there is a goddess *Pecunia* for a cult that literally worships money.  If you are turning human nature into anthropomorphic personifications (like happens in [*Hogfather*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett's_Hogfather)) this would be a natural, playing off the existing behavoir of those obscessed with wealth.

Speaking of *Hogfather*, you really need to [read some Diskworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discworld_gods).

> Gods on the Discworld exist as long as people believe in them and their power grows as their followers increase. This is a philosophy echoing the real-world politics of the power of religion and is most detailed in the novel *Small Gods*. If people should cease believing in a particular god (say, if the religion becomes more important than faith) the god begins to fade and, eventually, will "die", becoming little more than a faded wispy echo.

This is the same idea as you are contemplating.  The article goes on to give a fairly long list of ideas for you, though Pratchett was writing humorous saterical reflections of aspects of society.

Comment: Incidentally, Pecunia was an alternate name for Jupiter, according to St. Augustine: _“He is also called Pecunia,” say they, “because all things belong to him.”  Oh how grand an explanation of the name of a deity!  Yes; he to whom all things belong is most meanly and most contumeliously called Pecunia.  In comparison of all things which are contained by heaven and earth, what are all things together which are possessed by men under the name of money?_ City of God, Vol 2, Ch 12.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a handful of Gods of war, each with a different angle, maybe even warring between themselves for top position. I'm thinking digital warfare, guerrilla, autonomous, 'physical' combat, terror and any others.

There would probably be a god of data and information, protecting ones privacy. And many more smaller gods of digital technology like signal gods, battery gods, the god that can protect your phone if you drop it.

Then the gods of luxuries: food, travel (and fashion and money that have already been said) for example. At the moment maybe the gin and whisky gods are jostling for the position once held by Dionysus

Gods giving inspiration and reliable sales for music, movies and books.

Answer (score 1):

For new gods I would look at what things all humans have in common in this day and age. You have some old gods returning like the god of time god of death Exedra but you would also have new gods like the god of the internet for example. Maybe the god of travel, look for things that all humans having common regardless of culture or nationality.

Few more ideas

1. New superhero God.
2. A god of video games
3. The god of sports.
4. Some sort of nucular god.
5. A god of the internet and communication.
6. The god of travels and travelers.
7. A got a space and space travel who watches over those who Traverse the void between plants.
8. God of invention who inspires engineers to create new things.

A god of wealth and plenty